# Webflux statuscode can not be changed

Tags: spring-security, kotlin, spring-webflux

So I have one AuthenticationWebFilter to add a trigger when someone is Authenticated like this:

```
val builder : HttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeBuilder = http
            .addFilterAt(
                    CustomAuthenticationWebFilter(securityContextRepository),
                    SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION
            )
            .authorizeExchange().permitAll()
```

And then in "CustomAuthenticationWebFilter" I change the statusCode with some logic, somethig like this:

```
override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    return super.filter(exchange, chain)
            .doOnSuccess {
                    exchange.response.statusCode = UNAUTHORIZED
                    return@doOnSuccess
             }
```

The point is, when I am doing a request, the flow is going to before to the WebFilter

> AbstractServerHttpResponse#doCommit

and then the state is change to "COMMITTED" and when I call to

> AbstractServerHttpResponse#setStatusCode

it's not possible to change it.

It's possible to change the statusCode before be commited?

build.gradle

> compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
>       compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web')
>       compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config')

Comment: Can you add the solution and accept that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after testing so many things this days, I resolved it just changing the "SecurityWebFiltersOrder" to "SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION"